# HPUX: where is the "environment" file to set the variables?

Tags: environment-variables, hp-ux

On Slackware Linux, when I want to set an environment variable I edit this file

```
vim /etc/environment
```

On Solaris11, I can set a PATH with nonstandard dirs with those commands(I test the commands in the path with ssh without using the user-environment option and works fine)

```
svccfg -s svc:/system/environment:init setprop environment/PATH = astring: "/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/gm/bin:/opt/gm/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin" 
svccfg -s svc:/system/environment:init refresh
```

I still don't understand how to set a variable like this on Hp-ux, please don' answer
edit /etc/PATH
or
edit /etc/profile
because I had already tried it and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused by sshd because without the user environment option set to no doesn't found my files in /usr/local/bin even when I set correctly the variable PATH in /etc/profile and /etc/PATH.
If I compile ssh with

```
  --with-default-path=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

in configure, found my files in /usr/local/bin
So I think the correct answer is
/etc/profile and /etc/PATH to initialize environment(if you want to pass other variables to programs must edit `/etc/rc.config.d/nameprogram` or the init script of the program.